# {aka 'int (::)(esp_mqtt_event_t*)'} to type 'mqtt_event_callback_t' {aka 'int (*)(esp_mqtt_event_t*)'}

Tags: c++, mqtt, platformio, esp-idf

When i trying to build the code got error

`error: cannot convert 'MQTTManager::mqtt_event_handler' from type 'esp_err_t (MQTTManager::)(esp_mqtt_event_handle_t)' {aka 'int (MQTTManager::)(esp_mqtt_event_t*)'} to type 'mqtt_event_callback_t' {aka 'int (*)(esp_mqtt_event_t*)'}`

i try put a MQTT manager to a class, then i use the event handle to

```
esp_mqtt_client_config_t.event_handle
```

here is the `mqttmanage.h`

```
class MQTTManager
{
public:
    void begin();

private:
    esp_mqtt_client_config_t mqttCfg;    // MQTT
    esp_mqtt_client_handle_t mqttClient; // MQTT

    esp_err_t mqtt_event_handler(esp_mqtt_event_handle_t event);
}
```

and here is the `mqtt.cpp`

```
esp_err_t MQTTManager::mqtt_event_handler (esp_mqtt_event_handle_t event)
{
......
}

void MQTTManager::begin()
{
    Serial.println("---MQTT INITIALIZATION---");
    mqttCfg.host = MQTT_HOST;
    mqttCfg.port = MQTT_PORT;
    mqttCfg.keepalive = 60;
    mqttCfg.username = MQTT_USERNAME;
    mqttCfg.password = MQTT_PASSWORD;
    mqttCfg.event_handle = mqtt_event_handler;
    mqttCfg.lwt_topic = topicPubStatus;
    mqttCfg.lwt_msg = "0";
    mqttCfg.lwt_msg_len = 1;
    mqttCfg.lwt_retain = 1;
.....
}
```

what should i do ?

Learn Class and Making some device prototype

Comment: Pointer to member functions are very different from pointer to free functions. In fact, pointers to member functions are not actually pointers.